# Merging two lists of data in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

**I have the following example data**

**Data list 1**

2016-08-31  -  2

2016-09-07  -  2

2016-09-14  -  10

2016-09-21  -  2

**Event list 2**

2016-08-31  - Error y

2016-09-01  - Error x

2016-09-14  - Error x

2016-09-30  - Error y

**Is it possible to combine these into the following data, connecting matching dates between data and event**

2016-08-31   2  - Error y

2016-09-07   2

2016-09-14   10 - Error X

2016-09-21   2

Answer (score 1):

You can use e.g. `VLOOKUP`:
`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,F:G,2,FALSE),"")`

[`VLOOKUP`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1):

- looks for the date in `A2`
- in first column of `F:G`
- from the matching row returns value from second (`2`) column
- `FALSE`: looks for exact matches

[image]